# What is the difference between ionic-nav-view , ionic-view, and ionic-content?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view, ion-nav-view

I am new to ionic. I have been going through ionic docs, where I encountered `ionic-nav-view`, `ionic-view` and `ionic-content` directives. I am very much confused regarding them. Although, docs mentions clearly about `ionic-nav-view`, that it's required to keep track of navigation of user in your app. But it doesn't specify clearly about roles of `ionic-view` and `ionic-content` and when to use them and how they are related ?

Can you give a suitable example/scenario, through which it becomes easy to understand them ?

Apologizing for bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about ionic v1 or v2?

Comment: Can you explain in the context of both versions ?

Comment: just checked..all three are part of ionic v1.. there is an `ion-content` in v2 so got confused.. please use `ionic2` tag for ionic v2 only

Comment: I havent used ionic v1 to give you a proper answer though

Comment: Can you give explanation for ion-content ?